# Size classes not works in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uicontainerview, size-classes

I have added a custom container view controller and to it a `tableviewController`. As you can see down I try to set the cell's label's leading space with constrains. 15px is specified for `wAny, hAny`, 0px is for `wC, hAny`. But `wC, hAny` has no effect, why?

[image]

Comment: *Just a hunch… but…* try setting the first item to the superview and the second item to the label.

Comment: In the attributes inspector, switch the First Item and the Second Item.

Comment: if I switch, then it leading space always (iPhone / iPad) 0px